# Spring CodeConfig ScanAllAssemblies throws a ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, spring.net, spring.codeconfig

I'm trying out the new Spring CodeConfig for .NET but have tons of trouble with it.

I installed the NuGet package [Spring.CodeConfig](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Spring.CodeConfig) into an existing .NET 4 project, but have had nothing but trouble with it.

The ScanAllAssemblies method throws a ReflectionTypeLoadException when I run this code:

```
var context = new CodeConfigApplicationContext();
context.ScanAllAssemblies();
context.Refresh();
```

This happens even if I have defined no configuration class, but it also happens if I create a configuration class.

The LoaderExceptions property contains a single exception with this message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER))

I've tried adding an assembly redirect from version 1.0.3300.0 of System to version 4.0.0.0, which is the one that's referenced in my project, but this doesn't work.

How can I resolve this issue?

---

As requested, here are the references from the project in question:

- mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- Ploeh.Samples.MenuModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
- Spring.Aop, Version=1.3.1.40711, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07
- Spring.Core, Version=1.3.1.20711, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07
- Spring.Core, Version=1.3.1.40711, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07
- Spring.Core.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.4111, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07
- System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- xunit, Version=1.7.0.1540, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c

Since the second reference is a project reference, I'm also listing its dependencies:

- mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

I also have these binding redirects in my App.config - in case it matters:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Spring.Core" publicKeyToken="65e474d141e25e07" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.3.1.20711" newVersion="1.3.1.40711" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.3300.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

However, both were attempts to fix problems with CodeConfig. Removing them doesn't help...

Answer (score 4):

After some investigation, we've identified this as an issue the ReflectionOnlyLoad API under the 4.0 CLR.

The CodeConfig assembly scanning works under the 2.0 CLR but evidently despite no apparent changes in the ReflectionOnlyLoad API between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 there seem to be behavioral differences in the way ReflectionOnlyLoad handles dependent assemblies (or, more accurately, the way that we are programmatically resolving types for the ReflectionOnlyLoad API under .NET 4.0).

The Spring.NET team is working now on a quick updated release of CodeConfig (1.0.1) that should properly address this issue and permit its successful use under .NET 4.0.  Thanks for bringing it to our attention!